# How can I remove information bubbles for the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm using windows 10 and here's a picture from my taskbar. I'd like it to never show me the program information (In this case, I want the "Visual Studio 2017" label to disappear.
Can anyone help?

[image: [1]: See Image]

Comment: This is a fundamental feature of Windows it can't be prevented.  It has always happen.

Comment: Set the taskbar to auto-hide and you will see neither labels nor badges until the taskbar is shown.

Comment: @Alex M: Thanks for working to improve posts on Super User. But (1) you don’t need to download and re-upload an image to “inline” it — just edit the markdown. And (2) there’s really no need to take something like “[1]: See Image” and use it as the image’s alt text. It’s much more appropriate to use a description of the image, like «Close-up of taskbar, showing "Visual Studio 2017" hover text».

Comment: @Scott thanks. I'm new. I'm just taking quickie screenshots and ctrl+v'ing them back into the post. The first few times I added images, I took care with the alt text, but then noticed that I wasn't seeing it anywhere, so I kind of stopped bothering. I just find it's easier to understand a question if I can see the image alongside the question itself, and now I have permissions to do so, when I see one without, I've just gone and done it. Let me click edit and see if I can see what you mean by edit the markdown.

Comment: @Scott cool, I googled markdown and now I understand what I'm doing. Thanks for the gentle nudge in the right direction